# Elasticsearch: Indexing document throws error "Invalid index name [_doc], must not start with '_'"

Tags: elasticsearch, curl

I created a new index **a1**.

curl -XGET "http://localhost:41349/_cat/indices?v"

```
health status index                                  uuid                   pri rep docs.count docs.deleted store.size pri.store.size
yellow open   a1                                     ba3S75mbSWyNdP2XYip8VA   5   1          0            0       810b           810b
```

When I try to index the document to a1 I get error.

curl -XPOST "http://localhost:41349/a1/_doc" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"dummy": "data"}'

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_doc]"}],"type":"invalid_type_name_exception","reason":"Document mapping type name can't start with '_', found: [_doc]"},"status":400}
```

I tried with PUT. This also failed.

curl -XPUT --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:41349/_doc/1 -d '{
"school" : "Harvard"
}'

```
No handler found for uri [/_doc/1] and method [PUT]
```

Comment: which version of elasticsearch are you using ?

Comment: @ESCoder  5.6.15

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are using Elasticsearch version below 7.x. The error clearly states that mapping type name cannot start with `_`

> Document mapping type name can't start with '_'

You need to change your mapping type name (change from `_doc` to `doc`). Modify your curl request as

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:41349/a1/doc" -H "Content-Type:application/json" -d '{"dummy": "data"}'
```

Comment: @user2622678 please go through the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: @user2622678 since you are using 5.6 version, you need to add mapping type name that does not start with `"_"`